# How can I find out what category page I am on?

Tags: bigcartel

I want to have an if statement on `products.html` that checks to see if you are on a category page. For instance url is `site.com/category/hoodies` and I want to display a "hero" image for Hoodies category.

Maybe there there is a template for a category page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a multiple **page** variables that you have access to, documented here: https://help.bigcartel.com/developers/themes/#variables-1

`page.full_url` will do the trick in this case:

```
{% if page.full_url contains '/category/hoodies' %}
   <img src="http://website.com/image.jpg">
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I ended up doing.